# How to write multiple lines of text in a csv cell

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I started learning Python a couple of weeks ago for my thesis in social sciences with no prior programming experience. So please excuse any mistakes in my usage of programming/Python terms.

I want to scrape news stories from an online newspaper and store their date, H1, H2 and P tags in separate columns next to the URL in a csv, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kAta.png).

I tried first to get each of these results (date, h1, h2, p) into separate text files, and I would then manually copy & paste the content of these text files into separate columns in an excel doc. For date, h1, and h2, this method works fine, but I am having trouble with getting the p tags in order since it has multiple lines, which breaks the format I want to have.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
from time import sleep

def getdata(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
urlList = ["https://www.example.com/newsCategory/yyyy/mm/dd/newsStory1",
    "https://www.example.com/newsCategory/yyyy/mm/dd/newsStory2",
    "https://www.example.com/newsCategory/yyyy/mm/dd/newsStory3",
    ...
    "https://www.example.com/newsCategory/yyyy/mm/dd/newsStory1000"]

for i in range(len(urlList)):
    sleep(random.randint(5, 10))
    url = urlList[i]
    htmldata = getdata(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, "html.parser")
    data = ""

    year = url.split('/')[4].strip()
    month = url.split('/')[5].strip()
    day = url.split('/')[6].strip()
    date = year + "-" + month+ "-" + day
    with open("/path/dates.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        print(date, file=f)
    for data in soup.find_all('h1'):
        h1 = data.get_text()
        with open("/path/h1s.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            print(h1, file=f)
    for data in soup.find_all('h2'):
        h2 = data.get_text()
        with open("/path/h2s.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            print(h2, file=f)
    for data in soup.find_all('p'):
        p = data.get_text()
        with open("/path/ps.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            print(p, file=f)
```

As I mentioned, Date, H1 and H2 sections work properly, writing them to their text files on separate lines for each URL, which I can copy and paste to a csv to bring them together. But P part fails, as the original content has multiple lines of text for a P tag. So on the text file, a single news story also has multiple lines, which means they take more than one row on the csv.

Sorry if the code is an eyesore, as mentioned I am very new and I doubt this code which I created by adapting and merging different codes I came across online is perfect. Please let me know if there is an easier way to achieve what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*While using python there should be better approach as manually copy & paste from different files. So in general I would recommend to change your scraping strategy, but this needs an improvment of your question.*

> But P part fails, as the original content has multiple lines of text for a P tag

To answer your main issue based on the facts in your question, one approach could be to use the join/sep parameter of `get_text()`:

```
data.get_text('\n', strip=True)
```